# ¿Como puedo crear una variable con valores separados por comas al recorrer un objeto?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Quiero separar por con un - los datos de que sean del 10 al 20 o del 20 al 30 y así hasta 500. por ahora solo voy separando los datos con una ","

```
var accionnum = accion.Count();
var ListaAcciones = string.Join(",", accion.Select(m => m.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Deberías de ser algo más explícito, no entiendo muy bien tu pegunta. Podrías incluir el código de donde y como te llegan los datos que desean separar ?, Además escribir la salida que deseas de esos datos que recibes. O sea como entran y como deseas que salgan. Un saludo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822